# How do I get Code Examples to show in the Help file using Sandcastle Help File Builder?

Tags: .net, documentation-generation, sandcastle, shfb

I'm using Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI and I can't seem to get code examples in my comments to appear in the help file output.

I'm generating Help 1.x and MSDN-style HTML documentation.

The examples look like the following in my code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Connects to the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <example> Connecting to localhost
    /// <code>
    /// Client client = new Client(true);
    /// EndPoint localhost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8888);
    /// client.Connect(localhost);
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
```

Do I need to configure some Project Property which is unknown to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was you don't need to do anything.  Under **Documentation Sources** I'd added my *.csproj* and this was using the files under `bin/Debug` which weren't being rebuilt.  So the answer for me was to change the Documentation Sources to the files under `bin/Release`.  Stupid, I know.  I'll leave this here in case anyone else has the same problem.